# Can the derivative of a gauge-invariant quantity be gauge-dependent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I am wondering whether it is possible for derivatives of a gauge-invariant quantity to be gauge-dependent. Certainly, the converse is true; taking the curl of a gauge-dependent quantity (the vector potential $\vec{A}$) will give you a gauge-invariant quantity (the magnetic field $\vec{B}$).

Here might be an example: the Berry phase $\gamma$ can be calculated as the integral of the Berry connection. Taking derivatives on both sides would suggest that the derivative of the Berry phase (a gauge-invariant quantity) yields the Berry connection (a gauge-dependent quantity).

If this is indeed the case, could someone please help me understand *why*? Is it because the process of differentiation can bring in terms that are sensitive to the local phase? How/ when does this happen? What are the implications from a big-picture point-of-view? And in this case, should one actually be calculating things using the covariant derivative instead?

Comment: The Berry phase is gauge invariant if you integrate the Berry connection over a _closed_ curve. You can't get the Berry connection at a segment of a closed curve by "taking the derivative" of the curve -- that would only make sense if you had an open curve of variable length.